# How to create multiple plots stratified based on the same column

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am using python to try and iterate through the columns of a pandas dataframe and plot their data, stratifying each of the columns based on the grade of the respondent. here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def visualize():
    q = 0
    surveyData = pd.read_csv("Survey_1.csv")
    for (columnName, q) in enumerate(surveyData.iteritems()):  
        q += 1
        if(q > 2):
            plt.figure()
            ax = sns.barplot(x="grade", y=columnName, data=surveyData)
            plt.savefig(columnName)
```

and here is the error I am receiving:

```
TypeError: '('grade', 0        Junior
1        Junior
2        Senior
3     Sophomore
4     Sophomore
5        Senior
6        Senior
7        Senior
8        Senior
9        Senior
10       Senior
11       Junior
12       Senior
13    Sophomore
14       Junior
15    Sophomore
16    Sophomore
17    Sophomore
18    Sophomore
19       Junior
20    Sophomore
21    Sophomore
22       Junior
23       Junior
24    Sophomore
25    Sophomore
26       Junior
27       Junior
Name: grade, dtype: object)' is an invalid key
```

"grade" is the correct name of the column I am trying to stratify based on, and it works as an input when I'm not trying to iterate over all the other columns, but does not when I am iterating. Was wondering if anyone had any advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to get what do you want to plot, but if it's a count of each grade, you should try:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def visualize():
    df_count=pd.DataFrame()
    surveyData = pd.read_csv("Survey_1.csv")   
    df_count=surveyData.groupby('grade').count()
    ax=sns.barplot(x="grade", y="count", data=df_count)
    ax.savefig("gradecount.png")
```